# Laravel v8.x - Jetstream Inertia, 419 page expired on production

Tags: php, laravel, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream, expired-sessions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwPly.png)

page expired 419 appears when in production.
I've tried to run *php artisan clear:cache*, *php artisan config:cache*, *php artisan key:generate*, and also change the *SESSION_DOMAIN* with the same domain, but the page still error

if I deactivate the CSRF middleware it doesn't have an error, but I can't go to the next page.

I can run it on local, but when I use production database in local have the same error page.

Comment: Welcome to SO .. did read the doc ? https://inertiajs.com/csrf-protection

Comment: Simply add this in main blade <script type="text/javascript">
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            }); and in header tag  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

Answer (score 5):

i fixed it by removing this meta from the main blade.php template.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

because of this warning on inertiajs page:

> If you're using Laravel, be sure to omit the csrf-token meta tag from your project, as this will prevent the CSRF token from refreshing properly.

Comment: My blade file does not have this `meta line` and I am experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

I think it is possible there are two or more issues with the 419 PAGE EXPIRED.

I was never able to get it to work by changing the CRSF token, removing it, or disabling it.

I think the actual cause has to do with permissions with where the SESSION_DRIVER data is stored.

By default the .env has SESSION_DRIVER=database. Changing database storage to file storage SESSION_DRIVER=file works if your file permissions are correct. Once you have the file permissions set correctly, change back to SESSION_DRIVER=database if you so desire.

I was using SQLite3, and the only way it worked was if the database was in location ~/laravel/stoarage/sqlite3.database

Answer (score 0):

Using useForm instead of Inertia solved it for me.

Reference: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/inertia/inertiajs-vite-in-production-error-419?page=1&replyId=843186